# ASP.NET - Copying extra files on publish not working recursively

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I have a web application project that I want to publish to a web server.  There is a folder of files that are not included in the project, but need to be copied when it is published.  I found a few posts on how to do this copying with MSBuild, but I cannot get it to copy all files/folders recursively in the main folder I want to copy.

The folder I want to copy is (proj)/Scripts.  (This directory is excluded from the application project because I have all my JavaScript code in a separate project in the same solution, and this folder is copied from the JS project's output folder after it performs minification and other build tasks.)

Here is the section I have added to my *.csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="Scripts\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath> 
            <!-- whitespace and new line added for question readability -->
            Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)  
        </DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

This will copy any files in the top level of the /Scripts folder, but nothing in its subfolders.

How do I make it recursive?

---

**Fixed my own problem:**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="Scripts\**\*.*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

`<_CustomFiles Include="Scripts\*" />` had to be changed to

`<_CustomFiles Include="Scripts\**\*.*" />`

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="YourTargetDir\**\*.*">
      <Link>YourTargetDir\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```